# Angular js - $http cache time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, xmlhttprequest

hi as i read from the Angular documentation this is how to set the cache on $http request:

> cache – {boolean|Cache} – If true, a default $http cache will be used
>   to cache the GET request, otherwise if a cache instance built with
>   $cacheFactory, this cache will be used for caching.

I mean setting `{cache:true}` how much time the request will be cached for??

Is possible to set the cache max time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This cache keeps the loaded data as long as the full html site did not change. E.g. if you have a regular SPA the data are kept in cache for the full app lifetime. There is no build in way to set a maximum cache time. If you would like to clear the cache you have to do it by your self.

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
cache.removeAll();
```

More information regarding the $cacheFactory: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$cacheFactory